# Does /lib/modules folder must be on root device?

Tags: kernel, btrfs, modprobe

Just trying out things, I mounted a btrfs subvolume on /lib/modules, installed kernel on it. Everything seemed fine. But when I `modprobe` any module, it returned 0 without message and did not load that module actually. `dmesg` shows no related message, either.

And I found an exception. I have WiFi driver in updates/dkms. It can be loaded manually.

I wonder if there is restriction on this.

Comment: After adding a module does `dmesg` show anything on it?

Comment: @Rinzwind, no. No error, no module output (for some modules).

Answer (score 0):

> Does /lib/modules folder must be on root device?

No, it does not have to be on the root device.

There are 2 things to consider:

- `/lib/modules` needs to be available to the system at the same time as `/` is so it would not make sense to put it elsewhere. You can not guarantee that another partition is up and ready if it is on another disk.
- It should be on the root system to guarantee easy recovery from a corrupted system though.

> But when I modprobe any module, it returned without error

That means it got loaded. General rule in Linux: if it goes well report nothing back, if it goes wrong show a notice.

> and did not load that module.

I doubt that has anything to do with partitioning. If that was an issue I would expect you would not be able to boot at all.

Comment: I agree that in my case, the subvolume may not be mounted when init trying to load modules at boot. So I did not get all necessary modules loaded. But still it does not explain why modprobe did not work. As I stated, it returned without error but did not load the module actually.

Comment: No issue to boot is easy to explain, base modules are all in initrd.